# how to run junit tests that require classes compiled from clojure in intelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, clojure, cursive

I am working in Intellij with Cursive on a clojure project that has sub projects below it.  I imported the top level project asking the import to search for projects recursively.

Each of the sub module projects has a combination of clojure and java code.

To run all of the junits for a module, I can right click and choose run and all tests. This produces a target folder with all the compiled java classes, but it does not compile the clojure code, so those classes are not found.

There is a Leiningen task to compile the clojure code into class files, but these get put into a different target folder (along with the regular java classes)

The target folders are a combination of profile names.  The name created when running the junit tests is

> dev-module-name+base+system+user+provided

The target folder when running lein compile has all the same parts but in a different order,

> base+system+user+provided+dev-module-name

Is there a way to manage what target folder is used by a run configuration?  Or, is there a way to force the order of the profile names used in creating a target?